# Pycharm can't find declaration to go in remote session

Tags: pycharm

I'm working on a remote linux server. I run jupyter notebook in Pycharm and set the jupyter interpreter as the one on the server.

I opened a project in folder A and need old codes from folder B, which is not a subset of A. When calling functions from folder B, Pycharm shows can't find declaration to go. I tried to add folder B in the project structure as resource/source root. But I couldn't find the remote folder, and can only find a local copy of the remote folder. When setting the local copy as the resource/source root, it doesn't work.